# BASH Sleep & Send Keystroke to Program

Tags: linux, bash, keystroke

Issue: Start the Adaptec Utility in terminal and blink the second hard drive light. Sleep and submit a keystroke to end the blink.

```
> arcconf identify 1 device 0 1
Controllers found: 1
The specified device is blinking.
Press any key to stop the blinking.
```

Command: arcconf identify 1 device 0 1

Here are some commands I have tried.

1.) `echo -ne '\n' | arcconf identify 1 device 0 1`

Result: Starts the program and immediately submits an 'enter'. The utility is stopped before the drive can blink; I'm not sure how to add sleep here.

2.) `kill -9 8309`

Result: Kills the arcconf process, however, even with the process terminated the drive will forever blink.

3.) `echo -ne '\n' > /proc/8309/fd/0`

Result: Sends an 'enter' to the process, however, this only prints new lines to the terminal running arcconf and doesn't actually submit a keystroke. Same result with echo "abcd".

How can I start this utility in bash, sleep, and send a keystroke to stop the utility?

Comment: `echo -ne '\n'` is exactly the same as the plain `echo` with no arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to sleep for 5 seconds, try a bash process substitution

```
arcconf identify 1 device 0 1 < <(sleep 5; echo)
```

Another more precise option is to use [expect](/questions/tagged/expect)

```
expect <<'END'
spawn arcconf identify 1 device 0 1
expect "Press any key to stop the blinking"
send "\r"
expect eof
END
```

Comment: much appreciated, the bash process substitution does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Use shell statement grouping:

```
{ printf '\n'; sleep 5; } | arcconf identify 1 device 0 1
```

The pipe to the program's stdin will stay open until the sleep finishes.

Comment: swapping "sleep" and "printf" makes this work, thank you

Comment: The question says "The utility is stopped before the drive can blink", so I thought the problem was that it closed the connection too soon after sending the Enter.